# Having trouble creating a many-to-many relationship table in my flask blog app

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

While trying to make my own blog app, I wanted my Users to have roles so different users can access different parts of my blog. To add my Roles model I followed https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many documentation to create an association table along with my Roles Table.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from typing import Optional
import sqlalchemy as sa 
import sqlalchemy.orm as so
from app import db, login
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin
from flask_security.models import fsqla_v3 as fsqla
from hashlib import md5

roles_user_table = db.Table(
    "roles_user_table",
    db.metadata, 
    sa.Column("user_id", sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("roles_id", sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("roles.id"), primary_key=True)
)

class User(fsqla.FsUserMixin, db.Model):
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    email: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash: so.Mapped[Optional[str]] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(256))
    posts: so.WriteOnlyMapped['Post'] = so.relationship(back_populates='author')
    about_me: so.Mapped[Optional[str]] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(140))
    last_seen: so.Mapped[Optional[datetime]] = so.mapped_column(default=lambda: datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    role: so.Mapped[list['Roles']] = so.relationship("Roles", secondary=roles_user_table,
                                                        primaryjoin=(roles_user_table.c.user_id == id), 
                                                        secondaryjoin=(roles_user_table.c.roles_id == id),
                                                        back_populates="name")

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.email)
    
    def avatar(self, size):
        digest = md5(self.email.lower().encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        return f'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{digest}?d=identicon&s={size}'
    
class Post(db.Model):
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    body: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(140))
    timestamp: so.Mapped[datetime] = so.mapped_column(index=True, default=lambda: datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    user_id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey(User.id), index=True)
    author: so.Mapped[User] = so.relationship(back_populates='posts')

    def __rep__(self):
        return '<Post {}>'.format(self.body)
    
class Roles(db.Model, fsqla.FsRoleMixin):
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: so.Mapped[User] = so.relationship(secondary=roles_user_table, back_populates="role")

    def __rep__(self):
        return '<Role {}>'.format(self.name)
```

When I try to add a role in my Roles table by running the command:

```
admin_role = Roles(name="admin")
```

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper[User(user)], expression 'Role' failed to locate a name ('Role'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'app.models.User'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

An I setting up my tables correctly ? or is this issue occurring because of something else ?

Comment: Change the class name Roles to Role or change attribute to roles

Comment: Thank you !!!! This fixed my issue, now getting something else but better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the singular version of Role for your classname.

Please change this code:

```
class Roles(db.Model, fsqla.FsRoleMixin):
```

to:

```
class Role(db.Model, fsqla.FsRoleMixin):
```